# Suggestion for Android Javadoc and guide

Tags: android, javadoc

I would like to offer javadocs for android app sdk I am working on.  What is the best way to generate Javadoc that is comprehensive and includes links to android SDK?  Do I need to use Maven for this? I would like very high quality documentation like for Android SDK.

Comment: Also how to link a html guide into javadoc

Answer (score 0):

If you are using *Eclipse*, you can generate the javadocs using `Project -> Generate Javadoc...`. As for the formatting you should use, I recommend starting [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html).

Comment: Any issues with using eclipse in terms of showing all reference docs to Android SDK etc.

Comment: Thats one way to go is with eclipse. I was looking for eclipse vs. maven and whats the best way get comprehensive javadoc including references to android api etc.